# Automating google cloud SDK installation on windows, GCLOUD is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, batch-file, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am using following batch file to download and unzip the google-cloud-sdk,

file name: download.bat

```
set home=%USERPROFILE%
echo %home%
%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-179.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python.zip', '%home%/google-cloud-sdk.zip');& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('%home%/google-cloud-sdk.zip', '%home%/google-cloud-sdk'); }"
```

and I am using following batch file to install the SDK **silently** on windows,

file name: install_win.bat

```
call %USERPROFILE%\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\install.bat --path-update=true --usage-reporting=false --command-completion=false
```

After these steps are completed successfully when I try to authorize my serice account from another batch file using the following command,

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file {json fila path}
```

It fails and tells me that the glcoud is not recognized internal or external command.

Can anyone please help me solve this error?
I think the error is because of the lack of environment variable in windows with the bin file of SDK.
How to set that from the batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `...cloud...\install.bat` routine is `call`ed, hence it inherits the calling routine's environment. It does not communicate any changes back to the calling routine.

Since I'd assume that the `install.bat` is supplied by a 3rd party, hence cannot be altered, then you would need to retrieve the new `path` for the *current* `cmd` instance.

```
call %USERPROFILE%\...\install.bat ...
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('echopath') DO SET "newpath=%%a"
```

where `echopath.bat` is simply one line:

```
echo %path%
```

Provided `echopath.bat` is reachable - and it *must* be a separate file, not an internal routine - the new path should be returned (to `newpath` in this instance - I'll let you guess what changes you'd need to make to change that to `path`...)

Since executing an *external* batch loads the environment anew, the modified environment `path` will be reported by `echopath` and hence assigned to the variable nominated.